# Android nativedriver, starting an app with istrumentation

Tags: android, testing

I followed the steps that were written down [here](http://code.google.com/p/nativedriver/wiki/GettingStartedAndroid). Problem arises when I try to restart the app using adb command. LogCat shows the error:

```
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.simplelayouts/com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.simplelayouts-1.apk:/data/app/com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.simplelayouts-1.apk]
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4202)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.simplelayouts-1.apk:/data/app/com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.simplelayouts-1.apk]
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-26 20:40:30.455: E/AndroidRuntime(418):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4199)
```

I already put everything in the library path.

Comment: were you able to find what was wrong. im currently facing this. please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome.
In the Build Path settings in eclipse, I moved the server-standalone.jar file up in the order, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue earlier, the solution for me was to make sure my jar files were referenced properly in Eclipse and then **rebuild** the sample-layouts project. This rolls the jars up into the build so they will be found at run-time.