# Android native driver api error while running instruments command

Tags: android, testing

I am using android native driver api for testing the android native application.

I am following the guidelines mentioned the link [AndroidMakeAnAppTestable](http://code.google.com/p/nativedriver/wiki/AndroidMakeAnAppTestable).

But when I try to run the instrumentation command it doesn't shows any error in commandline but it shows in eclipse.

The error is :

```
04-17 11:13:14.460: D/AndroidRuntime(302): Shutting down VM
04-17 11:13:14.470: W/dalvikvm(302): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-17 11:13:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(302): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.simplelayouts/com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44dac250
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3966)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1901)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44dac250
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3963)
04-17 11:13:14.480: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  ... 10 more
04-17 11:13:14.520: I/dalvikvm(302): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception talks about ClassNotFoundException for the class that you are trying to load.

```
ComponentInfo{com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.simplelayouts/com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.testing.nativedriver.server.ServerInstrumentation in loader
```

ServerInstrumentation class file not found during run time.Please refer this link:
[Android nativedriver, starting an app with istrumentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024589/android-nativedriver-starting-an-app-with-istrumentation)

Comment: I tried to rebuild the jar file, but still it is showing the error.

Comment: Need that jar file on the classpath when your android application is running

Comment: where you have added the jar file during runtime?

Comment: Sory i am not clear about adding the jar file.. could you please tell me the steps

Answer (score 0):

Are you launching via Eclipse ? Right click on your android project node, go to build path, go to order and export and make sure server-standalone.jar is added and is 'checked'.